# AS3 access to stage variables inside a Symbol in another frame

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, symbols

I got a var called numOpp declared on frame 1, in frame 2 there is a symbol, inside the symbol code at his frame 1 (not the stage one), i want to use numOpp variable, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will work for you: `(this.parent as MovieClip).numOpp;`

Comment: It works thankYou!, but please can you explain me (this.parent as MovieClip) ?

Comment: @user3161756 when we want to get dynamic variable from a MovieClip (`numOpp` in your case) , we need to make "casting" , you can read more about it: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html